# Display Mp3 In ListView From Server Error

Tags: android, apache

I'm New in Android and  i having Issue I Wish and body Help me in it 
Now i'm trying to display mp3 fills from server using ivy put i'm having issue when click to play files 
Here is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    URL urlAudio;
    ListView mListView;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAudio);
        new getAudiofromServer().execute();
        new downloadAudioFromServer().execute();

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String url = null;
                Object o = myList.get(position);
                url = o.toString().replace(" ", "%20").trim();
                  playSong(urlAudio + myList.get(position));
            }});}


    private void playSong(String songPath) {
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songPath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private class downloadAudioFromServer extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            int count;

            try {
                URL url1 = new URL("http://server/1/");
                URLConnection conexion = url1.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();
                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url1.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Sounds/");
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    class getAudiofromServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting File list from server, Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                urlAudio = new URL("http://server/1/");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ApacheURLLister lister1 = new ApacheURLLister();
            try {
                myList = lister1.listAll(urlAudio);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    myList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
}
```

and my log is:

```
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.URL cannot be cast to java.lang.String
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at com.Infinityapp.naghmaty.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:56)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1128)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2826)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3585)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
09-15 09:28:40.630: E/AndroidRuntime(17264):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
playSong(urlAudio + myList.get(position));
```

line causing issue. so get String representation of URL because adding both String's as:

```
playSong(urlAudio.toString() + myList.get(position));
```

Comment: same problem I just want when i click on the item in listview to play the selected item in mediaplayer

Answer (score 0):

1.

This has a few problems:

This is essentially:

```
Object o = myList.get(position);
url = o.toString().replace(" ", "%20").trim();
playSong(urlAudio + myList.get(position));
```

The same as this:

```
Object o = myList.get(position);
playSong(urlAudio + myList.get(position));
```

String url is a local variable that you inialise here `url = o.toString().replace(" ", "%20").trim();`, but never use.

*So I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that, update the list? Please post that in a separate question (one question per post)*

2.

```
// Object o = myList.get(position).toString();
// url = o.replace(" ", "%20").trim();
playSong(urlAudio.toString() + myList.get(position).toString());
```

I perceive it to be a waste to create object o. Parse it to string, then concatenate with the url to string. And parse list items to string.

or

```
// again I'm only guessing your intentions.
String o = myList.get(position).toString();
url = o.replace(" ", "%20").trim();
playSong(urlAudio.toString() + url)
```

Let me know if this helps.